# How interconnected were Hydra and the U.S.S.R.?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, marvel, captain-america-civil-war, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

*Captain America: The Winter Soldier* and *Captain America: Civil War* show that

> at least some members of the the U.S.S.R.'s military command, such as [Vasily Karpov](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Vasily_Karpov_(Earth-199999)), were also members of Hydra.

Do we know how deep

> Hydra was in the Soviet government? Were they totally enveloped, like they were with S.H.I.E.L.D., or did they only control a few key players?

Or was it somewhere in-between?

Comment: Because Hydra is invisible, Hydra is powerful, Hydra is everywhere. Hail Hydra!

Comment: Hydra after World War II survived because the founders of SHIELD spared the lives of the surrendered and chose to use their scientific and technological expertise for the greater good, believing they have changed for the better. This allows the survivors to retain Hydra's philosophy and infiltrate into SHIELD, using it as a front while its true self remains hidden.

Comment: By comparison, German prisoners of war are treated very harshly by the Soviets - virtually all are condemned to work to death in the gulags. That gives Hydra survivors captured by the Soviet Union a much worse chance of surviving to rise again, unless the USSR did a similar thing to what SHIELD did. Barring that, it seems more likely that Hydra-in-SHIELD would have dispatched agents to infiltrate into the USSR and build a network from scratch, rather than use most-likely-dead compatriots captured by the Soviet Union.

Comment: Thing is Soviet paranoia and control over population would made any infiltration on the territory of USSR by foreign agent next to impossible.

Comment: OTOH, it's not unlikely that the Nazis had spies embedded in the USSR during the war.  They probably laid low and tried to blend in when things started going south.  If they were Hydra, they might be in positions to save certain POWs and rebuild in the new environment.

Answer (score -1):

Considering that Hydra was an arm of the Nazi military, I would think that any member of Hydra would have nothing but contempt for the Soviet Union. Look at how much European territory the defeated Nazis lost to the USSR. All of East Germany, and numerous other countries that had been conquered and annexed by the Nazis, became satellite nations and vassals to the Soviet Union as far back as 1945.

Comment: Hydra outgrew the Nazis. They're a parasitical organisation

Comment: Hydra outgrew the Nazis, but they were at odds with the Soviets for all of WWII and potentially long after.  I don't imagine that Hydra had an amicable relationship with the USSR.

Comment: They were also at war with the Americans and look what happened next.

Comment: Hydra does not regard governments as things worth of respect, only as tools.  If the USSR was more useful to them than Nazi Germany, they would certainly have no objection to dropping the later for the former.  They may have already been in the USSR while in Nazi Germany, particularly to avoid hitting other Hydra assets.