# Did HYDRA join the USSR when WW2 ended in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, hydra

We see in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* that HYDRA has a base in Siberia but now I’m wondering did HYDRA join the USSR after the war ended or did they just have an alliance in some way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that HYDRA just had a Siberian base but I can't find a source for that

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/53844/58193) and I think the answer there is mostly applicable here. I don’t have time for an answer now but it would seem that HYDRA is just everywhere working in the background. I doubt there’s any formal alliance or partnership.

Comment: HYDRA isn't a country. It's a... um... something something evil organisation... something...

Comment: Pure speculation here: 1. Hydra infiltrates SHIELD after WW2; 2. Some Russian agency infiltrates SHIELD later on, unaware that Hydra still exists in secret; 3. Hydra infiltrates that Russian agency.

Comment: an older similar question exists, so if anyone finds an answer to this, it would apply there as well https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127394/how-interconnected-were-hydra-and-the-u-s-s-r